# Question About UIButton And UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to place a UIButton with an image above my UITabBar.

I added this code in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method, but I'm getting some errors with `tabBar` being unrecognized.

I've built the TabBarController and NavController all in IB.

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addTabButton.png"];
UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addTabButtonHighlight.png"];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    button.center = center;
}
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Edit:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addTabButton.png"];
UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addTabButtonHighlight.png"];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.window addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your code of the outlets and properties in the .h file?
Is it possible that you made them in your main ViewController? Because `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is a appDelegate method and you normally shouldn't do UI things there, just in the viewControllers.

Comment: But this unbutton will be replacing the uitabbar's center tab, so it has to always be visible. how else should i do this?

Comment: Don't create your tabBar in the main window. Do that in the first ViewController. Move all your code like BobC said to viewDidLoad or viewWillappear of your mainViewController. If you want to display different Views by tapping the tabBar just create a uiView on your main ViewController and populate this with subviews. So your tab bar will stay untouched and always be visible.

Comment: What do you mean like that? Are you saying to have all my apps view as subviews of one main veiwController? Isn't that against the MVC?

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean. And no, it's absolutely not against the MVC design pattern. Because your views have their own viewControllers. Your mainViewController just displays but doesn't controls them. You can access a view of a viewController by calling his property `customViewController.View`.

Comment: Yinkou, thanks.  But my app is already build and has a complex view system and I don't think it makes sense to redo all of that.  I just need to have this UIButton show above the tab bar so I can put a custom image there.  My main.xib currently looks like this http://www.box.net/shared/static/b0dz86dka30tntharifp.png

Comment: Ay, i understand. Yeah that's hard. Then do it this way: create a button programmatically in applicationDidFinishLaunching and add it to the Window as a subview. Due the view hierarchy it will be above the tabBar.

`UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(120, 440, 80, 32);
    [btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.window addSubview:btn];`

Comment: Hmm i tried that but no button is showing. please check question with updated code.

Comment: Thats interesting, i've just tried it and it works for me. try a  [self.window bringSubviewToFront:button]; at the very end, just before the return. (don't forget to release it between that)
Do you add/bring to front any other views dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

applicationDidFinishLaunching is not the appropriate place to put such a method. Use viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: But this unbutton will be replacing the uitabbar's center tab, so it has to always be visible. how else should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are following this blog post http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/ to create custom TabBar but you are not following it properly. What you are doing is adding button as subview to normal viewController's View while you need to add the button to TabBar's View. Try to add button when your tabBarContoller is going to display. Like if you are removing navigation Controller's View from mainWindow and adding tabBarController's view there then before adding tabBarController's view to window add your button to tabBarController's tabBar.view so your code will look like this

```
[tabBarController.tabBar.view addSubview:yourButton]; 
[window addSubView:tabBarController.view];
```

Try and let me know what you got.....

Comment: So you're saying not to add the code to my appDelegate, and put it in any viewController where the tabBar is displayed?  Also, I don't have anything in the .h or .m for tabBarController because that was all setup in IB>

Comment: No I am saying before adding tabBarController's View to main Window add button to TabBar. You need to put the code in appDelegate.